# Share history between panes/windows

Tags: zsh, tmux

Is there a way to share the shell command history between panes/windows in a tmux session?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

shell history has precious little to do with tmux, it has to do with the shell you are using. So if you chose to use zsh it is enabled iirc by default. With bash you need to add some magic to your `.bashrc`

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n"
```

this appends your last command to history and reloads your history after each command. See [this post](http://briancarper.net/blog/248/) for more information.

Comment: I'm using ZSH by default, and for the record I have no idea what iirc means, but I assume it has something to do with the shell history;) So what might be the issue, in that case?

Comment: "If I remember correctly". So in this case I have assumed that you have that feature enabled already. If not I don't know.

Comment: if someone else finds this, new link for brian's post is https://web.archive.org/web/20170104092506/http://briancarper.net/blog/248.html

Comment: Is there an equivalent for `csh`?

Comment: append_history is [on by default](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#History) for zsh, but the history is only appended after a session is closed.

Answer (score 16):

Add these options to your `.zshrc`:

```
setopt inc_append_history
```

I also find `hist_ignore_dups` `hist_ignore_space` useful.

See also [Zsh » Options » History](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#History).

Comment: According to zsh documentation INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME, INC_APPEND_HISTORY and SHARE_HISTORY are mutually exclusive. Adding INC_APPEND_HISTORY is enough for history sharing between tmux panes.

Comment: @stephanos: Thanks. I removed `setopt share_history`